# Une nuance entre « Et ce » et « Je m'empresse de le dire »

Tags: expressions

> Nous voulons la même chose, Albert. **Et ce**, depuis le début.

I assume that « Et ce » is used to add (as an afterthought) an additional information that the speaker finds important. How does it compare with « Je m'empresse de le dire »?

> Nous voulons la même chose, Albert. **Je m'empresse de le dire**, depuis le début.

Incidentally, « d'ailleurs » is not to be confused with these two expressions, correct? Because « d'ailleurs » is more about adding information that is only peripheral?

> Nous voulons la même chose, Albert. Depuis le début, **d'ailleurs**.

Comment: *Et ce* just means *et ça*, *et cela*, I would translate it as *"and this has been the case from the beginning"*. I don't think *"je m'empresse de le dire"* is idiomatic, this sounds strange to me in this case. *D'ailleurs* is really close to *et ce* in this case.

Comment: As @SimonDéchamps says, "Je m'empresse de le dire" does not sound idiomatic to me. I would only say that if someone else was about to cut me off... so it sounds very specific, and I'm not sure I would use this exact expression....

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47628/discussion-on-question-by-luna-une-nuance-entre--et-ce--et--je-mempresse-de).

Comment: What happened to all the comments? I seem to recall there were more. And I can't find them under the "moved to chat" link...

Answer (score 1):

Historically "D'ailleurs" or "Par ailleurs" was employed to inputting an external thing to your talk. But today, your 3rd example is totally correct.
Your second example sounds in fact really strange.
Finally, the better and "perfect" way to said it is you 1st proposition.

Comment: I agree with Thibault. The second example is too "ampoulé" - I would not recommend it. The first and third are completely valid, and it becomes a matter of style to decide which one you prefer.